# Correct Code render block for iframe

Tags: html, iframe, httphandler

Is it possible to do code render blocks in an iframe control?

My iframe control has a src attribute that is pointing to an http handler, and passing the encrypted file path of the pdf file to display. e.g.

`<iframe id="PdfIFrame" runat="server" src="DisplayPdf.ashx?docid=" + <% 
Response.Write(EncryptedFilePath); %> ></iframe>`

But this code gets a parser error: "The server tag is not well formed". `EncryptedFilePath` is a public static property. I have tried using binding expressions (<%# %>) and the equals sign, but they all give the same parser error. Googling has not produced any results for me. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Judging by the lack of responses the answer appears to be "No".

Comment: Are there any solutions using javascript/jquery?